# ExtJs GridPanel Scroll to last Element

Tags: extjs, scroll, gridpanel

I am trying to scroll to the last Element of a GridPanel, the last Element is already focused by

```
_this.testpanel.getSelectionModel().selectLastRow( );
```

I have tried many ways but none of them worked...
The GridPanel is saved via

```
_this.testpanel =new Ext.grid.GridPanel(...
```

In the load function I tried

```
_this.testpanel.getRow(_this.receiver_list.getStore().getCount()-1).scrollIntoView(_this.receiver_list.getView(),false);
```

This one does nothing.

```
_this.receiver_list.getView().getRow(_this.receiver_list.getStore().getCount()-1).scrollIntoView("receiver_list");
```

This one scrolls the Form, the GrindPanel is inside. But not in the GridPanel itself.

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following function

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-setScrollTop

Answer (score 0):

Use [scrollTo()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-scrollTo) Elements method.